# How to switch to head/branch from different git repository

Tags: git

I have multiple working directories and a few repositories and would like to get one repository to be at the same point as another specific repository now, without merging any local changes. That is, I have this layout

- A: working Dir
- B: working Dir
- C: base repo
- D: working dir

The current state is:

- B was cloned from A at some point, it has diverged (as has A)
- B is pushed to C, D is cloned from C, thus D is a copy of B

Now what I need is to have D be the same state as the current branch in A, without the changes from B. What I though would work is

```
A> git push D master:alternate
D> git pull
D> git checkout alternate
```

But the files then still include the changes from B.  How do I get a branch on D, and working copy, to be the exact revision in A?

*NOTE: Directory D is not on the same machine and can't access A or B directly, only via C.*

Comment: Your sequence of commands looks fine (you wouldn't neet `git pull` though …). Are you sure you don't have the changes from B included in A already?

Comment: I changed `pull` to `pull path_a alternate:alternate`, then did the checkout and a `reset --hard` and it worked.  hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

If I got that straight, A and B aren't on "master". If they have diverged, why not creating different branches for them? And I really didn't understand the need for two working repositories on the same computer. Git handles that for you, without the need of replicating the data throughout your hard drive. That's exactly the beauty of version control.

Nonetheless, I didn't understand as well why simply creating a different branch won't solve it for you. If A and B ARE different, WHY keeping them on the same "branch"?

```
A> git checkout -b my_branch_A
A> git commit -a -m "whatever you have to commit"
A> git push D my_branch_A

D> git checkout origin/my_branch_A
```

By doing so you will have exactly you have on your repo A.

Comment: Why two working directories: Git only manages versioned files (obviously). When you do a "checkout" all the built/output files will not be switched. Thus you can't easily switch between branches unless you're willing to do a clean and rebuild of your project. Therefore I use two distinct working directories.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not quite follow how you manage your code, so I will list down your structure again. You have *TWO* working repositories when you started and *C* is the repository at *ORIGIN*.

You created *B* from *A* and work on both of them. You have a bunch of commits on both **A** and **B**. Then, you push *B* to *ORIGIN*(C in this case) and create a branch *D* from *ORIGIN*. Now, you want the changes you have done in *A* to be in *D*.

Well, for one, the snapshot of these branches is completely different. I would suggest you switch to branch *D* `git checkout D` and cherry pick the commits from *A* `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`

Cherry picking is the safest way to get code changes from one branch to another. Of course, this will also depend on how many commits you want to get into *D*. If there is a lot of code, then rebasing and merging would make sense.